# Moore neighborhood scanner algorithm working wrong. How to solve it?

Tags: python, algorithm, conways-game-of-life

A have an algorithm for scan cell moore neighborhood but it does not working can anyone find a bug here, because this problem driving me crazy.

```py
def moore_nh(cells, r, c):
    n = 0
    dr = [+1, -1, 0, 0, -1, 1, -1, 1]
    dc = [0, 0, +1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1]
    for i in range(len(dr)):
        if (0 <= r+dr[i] < len(cells)) and (0 <= c+dc[i] < len(cells[r])):
            if cells[r+dr[i]][c+dc[i]] == 1:
                n+=1
    return n

def next_gen(cells):
    clone = [[0]*len(cells[0])]*len(cells)
    for r in range(len(cells)):
        for c in range(len(cells[r])):
            n = moore_nh(cells, r, c)
            if cells[r][c] == 1:
                if n < 2 or n > 3:
                    clone[r][c] = 0
                else:
                    clone[r][c] = 1
            elif ((cells[r][c] == 0) and (n == 3)):
                clone[r][c] = 1
    return clone

print(next_gen([
            [0,1,0],
            [0,1,0],
            [0,1,0]
        ]))
```

I expected that this algorithm has printed

```
[[0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 0]]
```

but it prints

```
[[1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: `[[0]*len(cells[0])]*len(cells)` doesn't do what you think it does. All the rows are the same object.

Comment: With what can i replace it? (I have not programmed in python for a long time)

Comment: Use `clone = [[0]*len(row) for row in cells]`